# How to set character limit on the_content() and the_excerpt() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I set a character limit on the_content() and the_excerpt() in wordpress? I have only found solutions for the word limit - I want to be able to set an exact amount characters of outputted.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use a Wordpress filter callback function.  In your theme's directory, locate or create a file called `functions.php` and add the following in:

```
<?php   
  add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

  function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
  {
    // Take the existing content and return a subset of it
    return substr($content, 0, 300);
  }
?>
```

The `plugin_myContentFilter()` is a function you provide that will be called each time you request the content of a post type like posts/pages via `the_content()`. It provides you with the content as an input, and will use whatever you return from the function for subsequent output or other filter functions.

You can also use `add_filter()` for other functions like `the_excerpt()` to provide a callback function whenever the excerpt is requested.

See the [Wordpress filter reference docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) for more details.

Comment: Watch out, you might end up leaving tags open. There's some filter that will prevent that but I can't remember its name.

Comment: Found it, eventually, it's [balanceTags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/balanceTags)

Comment: Even balanceTags doesn't help if the tag is partially open.  E.g.: `<img src="example.jpg" alt="oh no! this is too lon"`.  My solution was to clear partial tags with
`$reversed = strrev($str); $reversed = preg_replace('/^[^>]*</', '', $reversed); $str = strrev($reversed);`

Answer (score 36):

Or even easier and without the need to create a filter: use PHP's `mb_strimwidth` to truncate a string to a certain width (length). Just make sure you use one of the `get_` syntaxes.
For example with the content:

<strike>`<?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 400, '...');?>`</strike>

**Update 2022**

`mb_strimwidth` breaks the HTML if the comment tag is used. use official wordpress `wp_trim_words` functions

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); 
echo wp_trim_words( $content, 400, '...' );?>
```

This will cut the string at 400 characters and close it with `...`.
Just add a "read more"-link to the end by pointing to the permalink with `get_permalink()`.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more </a>
```

Of course you could also build the `read more` in the first line. Than just replace `'...'` with `'<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Read more]</a>'`

Comment: It should be noted that if any HTML characters are present it could break the layout as the tags may not have their closing tag present.

Comment: wrap the php in a href and it will be a link without the read more.

Comment: @Uxair this 2022 updated solution appears to trim the content at 400 words, not 400 characters.

Answer (score 22):

[**`wp_trim_words`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/) This function trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text.

#### Example:-

```
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );
```

Comment: poster specifically said they already knew how to do that and wanted a char solution

Answer (score 16):

This also balances HTML tags so that they won't be left open and doesn't break words.

```
add_filter("the_content", "break_text");
function break_text($text){
    $length = 500;
    if(strlen($text)<$length+10) return $text;//don't cut if too short

    $break_pos = strpos($text, ' ', $length);//find next space after desired length
    $visible = substr($text, 0, $break_pos);
    return balanceTags($visible) . " […]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out [balanceTags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/balanceTags). I didn't know WordPress had that.

Answer (score 4):

For Using `the_content()` functions (for displaying the main content of the page)

```
$content = get_the_content();

echo substr($content, 0, 100);
```

For Using `the_excerpt()` functions (for displaying the excerpt-short content of the page)

```
$excerpt= get_the_excerpt();

echo substr($excerpt, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

`wp_trim_words()` This function trims text to a certain number of **words** and returns the trimmed text.

```
$excerpt = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">More Link</a>');
```

Get truncated string with specified **width** using `mb_strimwidth()` php function.

```
$excerpt = mb_strimwidth( strip_tags(get_the_content()), 0, 100, '...' );
```

Using `add_filter()` method of WordPress on `the_content` filter hook.

```
add_filter( "the_content", "limit_content_chr" );
function limit_content_chr( $content ){
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        return mb_strimwidth( strip_tags($content), 0, 100, '...' );
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Using custom php function to limit content characters.

```
function limit_content_chr( $content, $limit=100 ) {
    return mb_strimwidth( strip_tags($content), 0, $limit, '...' );
}

// using above function in template tags
echo limit_content_chr( get_the_content(), 50 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<?php the_content();?>` by the code below

```
<?php
$char_limit = 100; //character limit
$content = $post->post_content; //contents saved in a variable
echo substr(strip_tags($content), 0, $char_limit);
?>
```

[php substr() function refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

[php strip_tags() function refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', substr($post->post_excerpt, 0, 500) ) 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but thought I would add the functions I use that take into account any filters and any `<![CDATA[some stuff]]>` content you want to safely exclude.

Simply add to your functions.php file and use anywhere you would like, such as:

`content(53);`

or

`excerpt(27);`

Enjoy!

```
//limit excerpt
function excerpt($limit) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}

//limit content 
function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just to help, if any one want to limit post length at `home page` .. then can use below code to do that..

the below code is simply a modification of `@bfred.it` Sir

```
add_filter("the_content", "break_text");

function limit_text($text){

  if(is_front_page())
  {
    $length = 250;
    if(strlen($text)<$length+10) return $text; //don't cut if too short
    $break_pos = strpos($text, ' ', $length); //find next space after desired length
    $visible = substr($text, 0, $break_pos);
    return balanceTags($visible) . "... <a href='".get_permalink()."'>read more</a>";
  }else{
    return $text;
  }

}
```