# Display only the first sentence of a post on home page

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog with posts, and I am using the  quick tag to display summaries of blog posts in the /blog/ page. However, I would also like to show the two latest posts on the home page of my site, but only include a thumbnail, title, and first sentence.

I find that the  quicktag is perfect for the blog home page, but too much text for home page. And if I place the quicktag where I want it, then the blog home page looks a bit silly and short on text.

Is there a way to use the_content(), the_excert(), or other function to just pull out the first "x" number of words or characters to display on the home page only?

Comment: If we've helped solve your problem please upvote/accept our answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [How to set character limit on the_content() and the_excerpt() in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress).

From the answer:

> You could use a Wordpress filter callback function. In your theme's
>   directory, create a file called `functions.php` and add the following
>   in:

```
<?php   
  add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

  function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
  {
    // Take the existing content and return a subset of it
    return substr($content, 0, 300);
  }
?>
```

> The `plugin_myContentFilter()` function will be called each time you
>   request the content of a post/page via `the_content()` - it provides you
>   with the content as an input, and will use whatever you return from
>   the function for subsequent output or other filter functions.

Comment: function the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength) {
 $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
 $charlength++;

 if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
  $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
  $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
  $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
  if ( $excut < 0 ) {
   echo mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
  } else {
   echo $subex;
  }
  echo '[...]';
 } else {
  echo $excerpt;
 }
}
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );