# Display shortened post summary on WP homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress installation, I'm trying to display a short post text summary on the homepage (See attached image and text highlighted in red)

The homepage contains a stacked list of my most recent posts (the default one).

[image]
The two common solutions of which I'm already aware:

Solution #1 - The "Insert More" tag:- I don't want to have a "more" button. I simply need to have the featured image, author, categories and then the shortened post summary.

Solution #2 - Replace "the_content" with "the_excerpt" - I've looked for "the_content" inside my index.php and archive.php, and it doesn't seem to exist in those files. It exists in blog.php but changing it to "the_excerpt" does nothing, and there is no option for excerpts when creating a post.

My WP theme is [Qreator responsive WP](http://themeforest.net/item/qreator-responsive-premium-wordpress-theme/2034959)

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set character limit on the\_content() and the\_excerpt() in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
  add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

  function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
  {
    // Take the existing content and return a subset of it
    return substr($content, 0, 300);
  }
?>
```

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress)