# Showing just the first X words of the_content() only for mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

How would I go about showing just the first X words of the_content() but only for mobile devices?

Comment: More details please - how are you detecting mobiles?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `functions.php` file in your theme folder and do the following

```
add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
{
    if (wp_is_mobile())
        return substr($content, 0, 100); // Show the first 100 characters of content if the user is visiting using a mobile device
    else 
        return $content;
}
```

Note that I have not tested this but in theory I believe it should work.

Source:

- [Function Reference/wp is mobile < WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)
- [How to set character limit on the_content() and the_excerpt() in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
<?php
function getFirstXWord($string, $a) {
    $temp = explode(" ", $string);
    return implode(" ", array_slice($temp, 0, $a, true));   
}

echo getFirstXWord("this is a content but do not trust this content", 5);
?>
```

Here is a working demo: **[codepad](http://codepad.org/2t2vBkwz)**

For mobile detection part, you can use [php-mobile-detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) class. There is examples in project, I did not stated it here

Answer (score 0):

Two ways immediately come to mind.

One way would be to check the client's user agent with PHP, and then use `the_excerpt()` to get an excerpt of the post. You can use the code below to modify the length of the excerpt that you get back.

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', function() {
    return 20;  
}, 999);
```

For more information on `the_excerpt()` [click here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt); for more info on `add_filter`, [click here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

Alternatively, you could use CSS and media queries (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)) to handle mobile devices. Essentially you'd need two containers that hold your post content:

```
<div class="post desktop">
    Your post content here!
</div>

<div class="post mobile">
    Your mobile excerpt...
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: < target device width goes here >) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `content.php` you can change the following line:

```
<?php if ( is_search()) : ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

to

```
<?php if ( is_search() || wp_is_mobile()) : ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

You can set your excerpt lenght to what you want it to be